# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, no idea what i am doing wrong

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

getting this error when i want to run it:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at this line

```
for (File y: childfiles){   )
```

but strangely enough it depends on the directionary i chose if it works or not

```
   import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.lang.System;

    public class mainclass {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    String path = null; 
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter path:");
            path = scan.nextLine();

    File dir = new File(path);

    File[] files = dir.listFiles();


    for(File x : files){

        System.out.println(x);
        File[] childfiles = x.listFiles();
        for (File y: childfiles){


        if(y.toString().endsWith(".exe")){



           Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(

                   y.toString());
                    p.waitFor();


                    System.out.println(y.toString()+" executed, press enter for next exe");
                    scan.nextLine();


        }
        }

    }




        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`x.listFiles();` will return `null` for `file` (not `directory`)

[`listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)

> Returns `null` if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

So before both of your loop add a nullity check like below

```
if(files!=null){

}
```

Comment: how do i fix this? (sorry i'm very new to java)

Answer (score 1):

If x is not a directory, listFiles returns a value of null. You should change your code to add a check for this:

```
for(File x : files){

    System.out.println(x);
    if(! x.isDirectory() )
        continue;
    File[] childfiles = x.listFiles();
        //or add a null check
    if(childFiles != null)
        for (File y: childfiles){
            ...
```

I think it's safe to assume the dir file earlier on is a directory, but you could do the same there

Answer (score 1):

Always check `file.isDirectory()` before calling `file.listFiles()`.